# Select information from different table SQL

Tags: sql, ms-access

```
SELECT Boeking.reisnummer, (aantal_volwassenen + aantal_kinderen) AS totaal_reizigers
FROM Boeking
WHERE Boeking.reisnummer = Reis.Reisnummer
AND Reis.Reisnummer = Reis.Bestemmingscode;
```

Table 1 (Boeking) has aantal_volwassen and aantal_kinderen, and Reisnummer.
Table 2 (Reis) has Reisnummer and Bestemmingscode.

I have to show the total of aantal_volwassenen and aantal_kinderen. But i also have to show Reis.bestemmingscode which comes from a different table. Currently i have to enter a parameter, how can i solve this?

Comment: Use a join statement

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify all the tables in the `FROM` part of your query. The tables should then be joined (`JOIN`) to get the data you need.

```
SELECT Boeking.reisnummer
    ,(aantal_volwassenen + aantal_kinderen) AS totaal_reizigers
    ,Reis.Bestemmingscode
FROM Boeking INNER JOIN Reis 
    ON Boeking.reisnummer = Reis.Reisnummer
```